# In OTTO are all instances of a parameterized class the "same"?

Tags: java, otto

I thought I had a nice solution to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543951/how-do-i-effectively-use-an-event-bus) I asked, but now I don't think it will work out.

In Otto, if I do something like this:

```
@Subscribe public void foo(ApiRequestEvent<Foo> event) {
}

@Subscribe public void bar(ApiRequestEvent<Bar> even) {
}
```

It seems like both methods are called if I post any instance of `ApiRequestEvent<>` onto the bus. It that what is expected?

I am suspecting that this happens because in Java there is only really one class `ApiRequestEvent`, and Otto is looking at the class while ignoring the type parameters.

Before I abandon this approach, is there anyway around this? I was going to use this parameterized class as the "signature" for the events I wanted to subscribe to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. The type parameters will be ignored.

My typical approach is to define an Enum for all the event types, that the subscriber methods can check for to filter out events they are interested in.

Unfortunately since it can get cumbersome to enumerate all the event types, this of course doesn't scale very well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I ended up just using instances of the types since they had to be unique anyway.  In some cases were they were basically the same, i created a subclass and used that to keep them unique